# Template not work with Backbone and Handlebars

Tags: json, templates, backbone.js, handlebars.js, datatemplate

Here I have problem to render my template with handlebars and backbone.
I don't know why my each block doesn't work.
I rewrite my template several times and my json but it never work.
If someone have an idea of where my mistake here :)

here my index.html:

```
<body>
   <div id="page">

   </div>
   <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template">
       <h4> test template </h4>
       {{#each rappers}}
       <p>{{rappers.blazz}} !!!!!!</p>
        {{/each}}
   </script>
</body>
```

I got this result :

```
test template
!!!!!!
!!!!!!
!!!!!!
```

but not the {{blazz}} value ..

here my js:

```
var Rapper = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // defaults : {
    //   blazz: ""
    // },
    initialize: function() {
      console.log("Création d'un nouveau rapper");
    }
  })

  var Rappers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // defaults : {
    //   blazz: "pas de blazz"
    // },
    model : Rapper,
    url : './js/data.json'
  })

  var RapperList = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'#page',
    render: function(){
      var that = this;
      var rappers = new Rappers();
      rappers.fetch({
        success: function(rappers){
          var source = $("#template").html();
          var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
          that.$el.html(template({rappers : rappers.toJSON()}));
        }
      })
    }
  });



  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
      '' : 'home'
    }
  });

  var rapperList = new RapperList();

  var router = new Router();

  router.on('route:home',function(){
    rapperList.render();
  })

  Backbone.history.start();
```

And my JSON:

```
[
    {"rapper" : 
        [
            {"blazz" : "person1"},
            {"nom" : "paul"},
        ]
    },
    {"rapper" : 
        [
            {"blazz" : "person2"},
            {"nom" : "mike"},
        ]
    },
    {"rapper" : 
        [
            {"blazz" : "person3"},
            {"nom" : "jean"},
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you rearrange your data? An array of single-entry objects like that doesn't mesh that well with Handlebars, a single `{blaze: 'person3', nom: 'jean'}` object would be much easier to work with.

Comment: unfortunately I have to kept the formatting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution :

I slightly change the shape of the code. (and added a few more items in).

So here the new JSON :

```
[
    {
        "blazz" : "blazz1",
        "prenom" : "prenom1",
        "age" : 20,
        "album" :
            [
                {
                    "nom" : "album1",
                    "vente" : 1000}
                ,
                {
                    "nom" : "album2",
                    "vente" : 10068
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        "blazz" : "blazz2",
        "prenom" : "prenom2",
        "age" : 15,
        "album" :
            [
                {
                    "nom" : "album1",
                    "vente" : 1000}
                ,
                {
                    "nom" : "album2",
                    "vente" : 108798
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        "blazz" : "blazz3",
        "prenom" : "prenom3",
        "age" : 35,
        "album" :
            [
                {
                    "nom" : "album1",
                    "vente" : 6546
                            }
                ,
                {
                    "nom" : "album2",
                    "vente" : 4816
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

and here the new template :

```
  {{#each rappers}}
  <p>blazz: {{blazz}} prenom: {{prenom}} nom: {{nom}}</p>
  <ul>
    {{#each this.album}}
    <li>nom: {{nom}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
```

The difference is here :
Before :

```
{"object" : 
    [
        {"foo" : "content"},
        {"foo" : "content"}
    ]
}
```

And after

```
{"object" : 

    [
        {"foo" : "content",
        "foo" : "content"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<body>
   <div id="page">

   </div>
   <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template">
       <h4> test template </h4>
       {{#each rappers}}
       <p>{{blazz}} !!!!!!</p>
        {{/each}}
   </script>
</body>
```

By using directly {{blazz} and not {{rappers.blazz}

Comment: And this : this.[0].blazz ?

Comment: I got the same result